# Java - What the difference of setXY(x1, y1) and new Object

Tags: java

The problem I'm having is typing x1, x2, y1, y2 into begin and end.
This is what I wrote but it did not run as expected.

```
begin.setXY(x1, y1);
end.setXY(x2, y2);
```

After reading the answers for this exercise, I found that they used these two lines and it worked. I don't know the difference between these lines of code, please help me !!! And I'm a beginner in java and don't have much experience if you can give me some tips to learn

```
begin = new Point(x1, y1);
end = new Point(x2, y2);
```

this is my Point class

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    public Point () {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
    
    public Point (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
    
    public int[] getXY () {
        int[] array = new int[2];
        array[0] = x;
        array[1] = y;
        return array;
    }
    
    public void setXY (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

and this is my Line class

```
public class Line {
    private Point begin;
    private Point end;
    
    public Line (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
//        begin.setXY(x1, y1);
//        end.setXY(x2, y2);
        
        begin = new Point(x1, y1);
        end = new Point(x2, y2);
    }
}
```

this is my Main class

```
public class Ex2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Line a = new Line(1, 2, 3, 4);
        
        System.out.println(a.getBegin());
        System.out.println(a.getEnd());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can't directly call `setXY` on `begin` and `end` without initializing them first. At the start, they're both null, being fields that haven't yet been set. You need to set each to a new `Point` object using a constructor of the `Point` class. You could either call the constructor as `new Point(x1, y1)` as you've done in your 2nd snippet, or just do `begin = new Point()` at first and *then* set the x- and y-coordinates

Comment: I am wondering another problem. Class `Point3D` extends class `Point2D`, and this is code `Point2D p3b = new Point3D()` what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the getters and setter in your `Line` class and you should start getting the values:

```
public class Line {
    private Point begin;
    private Point end;

    public Line (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        begin = new Point(x1, y1);
        end = new Point(x2, y2);
    }
  
    // Just add this
    public Point getBegin() { return begin; }
    public Point getEnd() { return end; }
}
```